# Does the number of items in a Xamarin.Forms ListView's ItemSource affect its performance

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

This may sound like a silly question, since generally the greater the number of *anything*, the longer it takes.

However, I was unable to find any information (official or unofficial) about how performance is affected based on the number of items in a ListView. This was one of the many places I looked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance

Most threads/articles I read also only seem to talk about improving performance by selecting an appropriate caching strategy, nothing about the number of items in the `ItemSource`.

I realise it's hard to give exact values to my questions, but that's okay, I'm only after rough guidelines.

So my questions are:

1. Does having a small number of items in the `ItemSource` make a difference in performance, or is the caching strategy the determining factor?
2. Under what circumstances is it important to maintain as small an `ItemSource` as possible?

I realise that this may not be an exact question, and can potentially be interpreted as a discussion, but guidelines here are all that's required to suffice as an answer. It's important that I design this part of the application correctly from the start, to avoid performance issues down the track.

Comment: if you're concerned about performance, use CollectionView

Comment: @Jason Thanks, I’ll look into CollectionView. However I still require closure regarding ListView. Surely performance is an issue for everyone these days with need for smooth scrolling, not just me. So given that, why is ListView still a thing? Why not just deprecate it and use CollectionView everywhere?

Comment: my guess is that once CollectionView is fully mature ListView will be deprecated.  But there are thousands of apps that have relied on it for 5 years and still need it suspported